# IE8 - Cursor can not move to the end of the last smiley in CK Editor

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, ckeditor

When I insert data in ckeditor with smiley, I want to edit data again but I am not able to click after the smiley is inserted.
Unable to put text in ckeditor for ie8 after smiley. If I want to keep text or smiley after that, the mouse cursor wouldn't move to the end of smiley. But if I used end button of keyboard then mouse cursor appears after smiley. This is problem on IE 8 only.